# my sql trigger update another table and doesnt allow change culomn

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have two table

1. city with id, name, populity, state_id
   2.state with id, name, populity
   i want to use trigger when city populity changes and update state populity and doesnt allow user to change state populity using trigger
   i have written some mysql trigger code but it got errored with 1064 error code
   you can see my code here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER populityy
AFTER UPDATE
ON `city`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.populity <> old.populity
    THEN
        UPDATE `state` SET populity = populity + new.populity - old.populity WHERE id = new.state_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

please help me

Comment: 'In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html